# Bad experience: PDF to ImageField and similar Drupal modules

Tags: media, files

I can not make them work (PDF to ImageField, PDF Preview and PDFThumb), No errors, no status report messages. Simply it doesn't show the preview as it should.

Comment: Welcome to SE. You might want to add a lot more detail to this question. Have you checked module permissions? Have you followed documentation?